# Swift - Core Data: destroyPersistentStoreAtURL throwing error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want an option in my app to reset all of my data. I created a class named `CoreDataStack` and put all of my core data code in it with this function:

```
func dropAllData() throws {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(applicationDocumentsDirectory, withType:NSSQLiteStoreType , options: nil)        
    try addStoreCoordinator(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, storeURL: applicationDocumentsDirectory, options: self.options)
}
```

I then have this function in my `AppDelegate`:

```
func dropTables() {
    do {            
        try stack.dropAllData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I've used this function before to delete my data with success, but suddenly I can't delete anything and I keep receiving this error when I call `dropTables()`.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134000 "(null)" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/59E4B2FB-E0E4-4527-8793-253864A2DE83/data/Containers/Data/Application/33D1C5CF-94B8-4897-A77F-A10DDFEF92D6/Documents/}

I've tried searching for this error and couldn't find anything (or I'm just looking in the wrong places). I also tried deleting the app from the device, reinstalling, and trying again but get the same result. Does anyone know what this error is and why can't delete my database?

Comment: You should have to delete all records rather then dropping tables...!!

Comment: "134000" is a `NSPersistentStoreInvalidTypeError` - see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Persistent_Store_Error_Codes).  It looks like `applicationDocumentsDirectory` points to the application's `Documents` directory, rather than the SQLite file?